# Validating Django Forms Via Related Fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am new to Python and django and am having trouble implementing model form validation.

I have a form where users can sign-up for multiple workshops. I want to validate the form such that a user cannot sign-up for workshops with overlapping time slots.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to access the time data I need to make the comparison.

Questions:

1. How can I access the related time data from the Workshop model and filter it by the form input?
2. How can I make the comparison of the multiple items this data will return?

When I run the code below, I get the "too many values to unpack" error. I understand why this is happening but don't know how to access the information in the array to make my comparisons.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Workshop(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tuition = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(

class Registration(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    workshop = models.ManyToManyField(Workshop)
```

forms.py

```
from django.db import models  
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Registration, Workshop
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Registration
        exclude = ['user']

    def clean(self):
        workshop = self.cleaned_data.get('workshop')
        startTime = Workshop.objects.get('workshop__start_time')
        endTime = Workshop.objects.get('workshop__end_time')
        if (startTime > endTime) or (startTime == startTime): 
            raise ValidationError("Workshop times overlap.")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the conceptualisation is not very clear, for starters should it not be called `RegisteredUsers` instead of `Registration`(which is verb and not noun) and if `workshop` is a many-to-many field it should perhaps be named `workshops` as it save multiple entries. Apart from that your problem can be solved like this :

1) In clean `workshop = self.cleaned_data.get('workshop')` , it can (probably is) return multiple values to workshop, lets rename it like this `workshops = self.cleaned_data.get('workshops')`
2) iterate over the `workshops`, your query should check for 3 different types of overlap, one when the workshop in question is completely included in one or more other such workshops for this user, second when the workshop starts after one or more workshops but finishes before them, and third when it starts before other workshops but finishes after one or more of them, like this :

```
from django.db.models import Q
    for workshop in workshops:
        if (workshops.filter(Q(start_time__gte=workshop__start_time),Q(end_time__lte=workshop__end_time) |
                             Q(start_time__lte=workshop__start_time),Q(end_time__gte=workshop__start_time)|
                             Q(start_time__lte=workshop__start_time),Q(end_time__gte=workshop__start_time)).count()>1): # count>1 is used because one of the result of filter will be the same workshop object that we are checking against
            #there is an overlap, put your overlap handling code here
        else:
            #there is no overlap, put your saving the data code here
```

The only assumption here is that workshops is a queryset and not a list, in case its a list convert it back to queryset by gathering the ids of all workshops in a list and do this to get a queryset of workshops :

```
workshops = Workshop.objects.filter(pk__in=list_of_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to check for overlap every time a user registers, it will be a heavy job. Instead what you can do is check for overlap when workshops are getting inserted. Then you can have a overlap table which stores overlapped workshops. That way you can warn user if he's registering to two workshops which overlap by checking for the same in overlap table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lt`(less than) or `gt`(greater than) [methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#lt) from django queryset. If exists a workshop that `start_time > workshop.end_time` and `start_time = workshop.start_time` raise the error.

```
 def clean(self):
        workshop = self.cleaned_data.get('workshop')
        overlaping = Workshop.objects.filter('start_time__gt'=workshop.end_time,\
                                     'start_time'=workshop.start_time).exists()
        if overlaping:
              raise ValidationError("Workshop times overlap.") 
        return self.cleaned_data
```